# Probability to put wires in right connectors

Tags: probability, permutations

I have a little board to control the lights of my Chrismast Tree which need to be fixed :

[image: board to fix]

If you see, on the top, There are 4 connectors, and 3 wires (1 connector and 1 wire are in the correct place.)

**My objective is to know the probabilities to put the corrects wires on correct connectors.**

$Where:$

$n$= numbers of connectors

$k$= numbers of wires

$$_nP_k= \frac{4!}{(4-3)!}$$

$$_nP_k = 24$$

If I compute all permutations in python:

```
import itertools as it

items = 'c1','c2','c4','c5'

prob = it.permutations(items,3)

count=0
for i,j,k in prob:
    print(i,j,k)
    count+= 1
    
print('permutations totals : {}'.format(count))
```

I get the all permutations:

```
c1 c2 c4
c1 c2 c5
c1 c4 c2
c1 c4 c5
c1 c5 c2
c1 c5 c4
c2 c1 c4
c2 c1 c5
c2 c4 c1
c2 c4 c5
c2 c5 c1
c2 c5 c4
c4 c1 c2
c4 c1 c5
c4 c2 c1
c4 c2 c5
c4 c5 c1
c4 c5 c2
c5 c1 c2
c5 c1 c4
c5 c2 c1
c5 c2 c4
c5 c4 c1
c5 c4 c2
permutations totals : 24
```

If I do the frecuentist approach I get :

$$ P(\text{connectors in correct place}) = \frac{1}{24} $$

So I have aproximately 4.16% probability to put wires in the rights connector on the first attempt.

Am I good on my appreciation ?

Comment: I will assume that no more than one wire can be attached to each individual connector.  The probability you choose the correct connector for the first wire is $\frac{1}{4}$.  Given that your first guess was correct, the probability you guess correctly for the second wire is $\frac{1}{3}$ and finally for the last given the first two were correct is $\frac{1}{2}$.  Multiplying these together gives $\frac{1}{4\times 3\times 2} = \frac{1}{24}$.  Manually listing these out and counting them is a waste of time and effort.  Learning how to count without using your fingers and toes is a useful skill.

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz.  You aproach was conditional probability ?

Comment: It could just as well be explained as the Multiplication Principle *of probability* as it could be explained as the Multiplication Principle *of counting*.  There being $4\times 3\times 2$ ways to pair the wires to the connectors, only one of which being correct.  See [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) for the counting principle and [Conditional Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) for the probability focused interpretation.

Comment: I mean $P(A) = \frac{1}{4}$ ,$P(B|A) = \frac{1}{3}$, $P(C|B,A) = \frac{1}{2}$ ?